# Setting the compiler path on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In my computer  c_cpp_properties.json file looks like this,

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Is the compilerPath and intelliSenseMode  are correct ?

or compilerPath should be something like this

```
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++
```

or

```
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
```

also intelliSenseMode should be "gcc-x64", or "clang-x64"  or "msvc-x64" ?

For instance in Microsoft Vs Code site above code changed to

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                 "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_configure-the-compiler-path

So the main problem is how can I be sure about the what to use in compilePath
Thanks

Comment: What are the symptoms that makes you question if the configuration is correct?

Comment: In other sites they are changed and made some additions os I cannot be sure which one I can use..

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56818025/edit) your question and claify what unexpected things that are happening in detail.

Comment: I can tell you that the compiler path should not be `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++ `

Comment: I am confused at what you are getting at here with the question. I believe you should prefer using / over \ as the path separator if that is the question.

Comment: ***So the main problem is how can I be sure about the what to use in compilePath*** it has to match where your compiler is actually located. Since there are different possibilities of where `mingw` is installed (and different versions of mingw / mingw64) your path can be different than examples you see online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, in the official Visual Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), you can see that the compiler path and intelliSenseMode are set as shown below. Just make sure to give the right location of `g++.exe`.

```
"compilerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
"intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
```

Update the question with what issues you are noticing if you have any.

Answer (score 2):

The `compilerPath` and `intelliSenseMode` variables serve the purpose of configuring the VSCode editor to provide compilation and IntelliSense services respectively.

## `compilerPath`

Because VSCode isn't a full IDE by itself, it doesn't ship with the compiler it needs to offer the compilation service. Therefore, it needs to be pointed in the direction of a valid C++ compiler. That is the purpose of the `compilerPath` variable. Testing whether or not the path you provided is correct is easy. Copy and paste it into a terminal (*CMD or PowerShell*) and see if the resulting output looks something like this:

```
PS C:\Users\neilb> C:\"Program Files"\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
PS C:\Users\neilb>
```

This means that the path is valid. If it isn't, locate where your install of MinGW (*the library that provides `gcc` and `g++` support on Windows*) is. If not already installed, [do so](http://www.mingw.org/download/installer).

## `inteliSenseMode`

This tells VSCode what C++ style guide to follow for formatting code and providing linting features. The full list of options here is listed on the [`VSCode-cpptools` GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md#intellisensemode). What you have currently set should be adequate. (`clang-x64`)