# VS Code: Using compiler in a directory that is not in path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanted to compile my programs in VS Code with a compiler stored on a USB, is there any way I can set it up? Any setting, or parameter in configs?

I tried looking in settings for an option which seemed like they'd help but to no avail.

Comment: What language/compiler?

Comment: For any, though for now I'm sticking with gcc

Comment: Does [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties) help? (notably, the `compilerPath` property?)

Comment: I'd say this also answers your question too [Setting the compiler path on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818025/setting-the-compiler-path-on-windows)